# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null - DOM loaded but still not working

Tags: javascript

I understand this is a heavily trodden error, yet I can't seem to get rid of it. My element, productprice, should be loading into the DOM perfectly fine. All of the syntax looks as it should to my eyes. The point of this code is to display the JSON data in a table in order to form the products page of a generic shopping website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Min Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="products">
    <table id="prodtable">
      <tr id="headers">
        <th id="prodnameheader">Name </th>
        <th id= "proddescheader">Description  </th>
        <th id= "prodpriceheader">Price  </th>
        <th id= "prodcategory">Category  </th>
        <th id="firstprodimgeheader">1st image  </th>
        <th id="secondprodimageheader">2nd image  </th>
        <th id="thirdprodimageheader">3rd image  </th>
        <td id="productname"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="name">
      </tr>
      <tr id="description">
      <tr>
      <tr id="price">
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
  function get_json(fileName, callback){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        if(typeof callback == "function"){
          callback(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
        }
      } else {
        console.error("Could Not Read JSON, error: " + 
xmlhttp.status);
      }
    }
    };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", fileName, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
   }


  function display_json(obj){
    var x = 0;
    for (i in obj.products){
      var prodname = 
    document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj.products[x].name));
      var prodprice = 
document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj.products[x].price));
      var proddesc = 
document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj.products[x].description));

      var tablename = document.createElement("td");
      tablename.setAttribute("id","productname");

      var tableprice = document.createElement("td");
      tableprice.setAttribute("id","productprice");

      var tabledescription = document.createElement("td");
      tabledescription.setAttribute("id","productdescription");

      tablename.appendChild(prodname);
      tableprice.appendChild(prodprice);
      tabledescription.appendChild(proddesc);

      document.getElementById("productname").appendChild(prodname);
      document.getElementById("productprice").appendChild(prodprice);

document.getElementById("productdescription").appendChild(proddesc);

      for (c in obj.products.images){
        var firstprodimge = 
document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj.products[x].images[0]));
        var secondprodimage = 
document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj.products[x].images[1]));
        var thirdprodimage = 
document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(obj.products[x].images[2]));
        }
        x++;
      }
  }
  window.onload = function(){
    get_json("products.json",display_json);
  }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.setAttribute()` to set the "id" of an element node. Just `tablename.id = "productName";` will do it.

Comment: `productprice` isn't in the dom.

Comment: Right, you have to add the new `<td>` elements to the DOM before you can find them in `document`.

Comment: How come it isn't in the DOM currently? What am I not doing that I should be?

Comment: You didn’t append tablename, tableprice, tabledescription to the existing dom.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td id="productname"></th>
```

and here

```
 <tr id="name">
 </tr>
 <tr id="description">
 <tr>
 <tr id="price">
 </tr>
```

are obvious faults...

Comment: How so? How do I rectify the faults?

Comment: <td> should match to </td>, not </th> and <tr> should be closed, instead of opened again at the description..